# How to determine the Absolute path for specific file from Assets?

Tags: javascript, android, android-assets

In an iPhone Application, I just write one line to get the complete path for a specific file ( as below ).

```
NSString *strPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myjavascript" ofType:@"js"];
```

My question is How to get the complete path for a specific file which is located under **Assets folder in Android**.

Sample Image.

[image]

Comment: means you need filesystem path?

Comment: @chirag - yes ! exactly - I need file-system-path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assets are compiled into .apk file (which basically is zip file). You can't get system path into zip file. You have to manually unzip .apk to some folder and get file system path to *asset* folder and files inside that folder.

But it sounds like you don't really need a path to asset files. You should look into these functions:

[Context.getAssets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets%28%29)
[AssetManager.open(String fileName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29)
[AssetManager.openFd(String fileName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#openFd%28java.lang.String%29)

These functions allow you to get input stream or file descriptor for any of your assets. Here is an example:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream assetIn = assetManager.open("excanvas.js");
//do something with assetIn...
```

You need to specify path to your asset relatively to *asset* folder.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I was then able to use the InputStream to call BitmapFactory.decodeStream().