# How to pass a file path which is in assets folder to File(String path)?

Tags: android, xml, file-io, assets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - How to determine the Absolute path for specific file from Assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744169/android-how-to-determine-the-absolute-path-for-specific-file-from-assets)

I am trying to pass a file to File(String path) class. Is there a way to find absolute path of the file in assets folder and pass it to File(). I tried `file:///android_asset/myfoldername/myfilename` as path string but it didnt work. Any idea?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't create a `File` from an assets file because these are stored in the apk, that means there is no path to an assets folder.

But, you can try to create that `File` using a buffer and the [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) (it provides access to an application's raw asset files).

Try to do something like:

```java
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = am.open("myfoldername/myfilename");
File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);

private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

   try{
      File f = new File(my_file_name);
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
      byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
      int length = 0;

      while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
      }

      outputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();

      return f;
   }catch (IOException e) {
         //Logging exception
   }

   return null;
}
```

Let me know about your progress.

Comment: not working missing method

Comment: man your code is all messed up, you really need to make it clear

Comment: @desgraci, Sorry. It's done. I didn't realize how confuse it was. Copy paste things :D

Comment: thanks man, but you missed the return :p

Comment: so you are saying whenever we need we need to write into a file ? doesn't sounds good !!

Comment: It might help to add the dir to write the file to, e.g. :  File f = new File(getFilesDir()+"/my_file_name.jpg");

Answer (score 10):

Unless you unpack them, assets remain inside the apk. Accordingly, there isn't a path you can feed into a File. The path you've given in your question will work with/in a WebView, but I think that's a special case for WebView.

You'll need to unpack the file or use it directly.

If you have a Context, you can use `context.getAssets().open("myfoldername/myfilename");` to open an InputStream on the file. With the InputStream you can use it directly, or write it out somewhere (after which you can use it with File).

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helped. but the code below saves me from writing the file somewhere.

Comment: @akd which code below? Are you talking about yugidroid code? Because that code is creating a new file is it not?

Comment: this was back in 2012. I can't remember really. but I guess I am talking about yugidroid code as there are only 2 answers. And I guess as yugidroid stated that it provides access to an application's raw asset files instead of creating a file.