# Android Reading PDF files from asstes folder

Tags: android, android-layout, pdf, android-intent, android-listview

I have list of PDF files need to Place in asstes folder,my requirement is to read files from asstes and display it inside a listview.
if we click on each list item need to read respective PDF file

I have followed this blog  http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-read-pdf-files-in-android.html

But here they have given reading a PDF files from External Storage Directory

I want to implement the same reading files from Asstes Folder

Could any one help How to implement the same example reading files from asstes?

Comment: check this [link][1] link may help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820142/how-to-pass-a-file-path-which-is-in-assets-folder-to-filestring-path

Comment: hi just see the answer which i posted hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot open the pdf file directly from the assets folder.You first have to write the file to sd card from assets folder and then read it from sd card.

Try out the below code to copy and read the file from assets folder:

```
 //method to write the PDFs file to sd card 
 private void PDFFileCopyandReadAssets()
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "test.pdf");
        try
        {
            in = assetManager.open("test.pdf");
            out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            readFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/test.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void readFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

Open the file from sdcard as below:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.pdf");        
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also provide a permission to write into your external storage in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: @GrlsHu question is about  for pdf file

Comment: @GrlsHu what is the directory name  in SD card the file is  created from Assets?

Comment: You can specify your own directory name of sd card in which you want to create and store the pdf file.

Comment: please provide some example code of line(creating Directory in SD card)

Comment: Final question i am implementing a Books Application(PDF Files reading)Is there any way to read the files from with in our Application?

Comment: What do you mean by read file with in our application  ? Are you storing all the pdfs in your assets folder ?

Comment: yes i want to store the PDF files in assets folder, Is there any best option?