# How to share file from assets folder

Tags: android, android-intent

I know how to share file from SD Card, but this time i have to share file from assets folder.

See below code, which i used to share file from SD

```
String fileToShare = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/Downloads/" + fileName;
newFile = new File(fileToPrint);
Intent intent = new Intent();   

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("audio/mp3");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You'll need to copy your file out of assets first.

Comment: i already have file in assets folder @323go

Comment: Very good. Now you have to copy it *out of* assets to SD card.

Comment: i know that way but i want to know how can i share directly from assets ?

Comment: In that case, you'll need to implement a `ContentProvider`. That's not terribly difficult, but copying is slightly less work.

Comment: what you think will this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820142/how-to-pass-a-file-path-which-is-in-assets-folder-to-filestring-path work for me ? @323go

Comment: This is where you have to start doing your own work. Try it.