# How to integrate a interactive pdf viewer with in the android application

Tags: android, pdf, assets, interactive

I am unable to read PDF file from assets folder. how could i read a PDF in a single page with integrating all controls available for a PDF viewer. I don't want to open a default pdf viewer available in the phone.  Please suggest me the right way to achieve interactive PDF viewer  with in the android application which can read the pdf from assets/raw folder from the android resource components. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intent` to load your PDF in external application.

```
File file = //Load your file from assets here
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can load file from assets using `InputStream`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11820891/2741586) post.

Good luck!

Comment: Really are you calling this integration of a PDF READER? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**It helped for me:**

### Barteksc Android Pdf SDK Library

> Android PdfViewer AndroidPdfViewer 1.x is available on the
> AndroidPdfViewerV1 repo, where can be developed independently. Version
> 1.x uses a different engine for drawing documents on canvas, so if you don't like the 2.x version, try 1.x.
>
> Library for displaying PDF documents on Android, with animations,
> gestures, zoom, and double-tap support. It is based on PdfiumAndroid
> for decoding PDF files. Works on API 11 (Android 3.0) and higher.
> Licensed under Apache License 2.0.

Which supports Android devices from Android 4.4.4 (KitKat)

### Installation

Add to build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
```

or if you want to use more stable version:

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

### Add this into your layout file:

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/your_pdf_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

### You can Load a PDF file like this:

```
pdfView.fromUri(Uri)
or
pdfView.fromFile(File)
or
pdfView.fromBytes(byte[])
or
pdfView.fromStream(InputStream) // stream is written to bytearray - native code cannot use Java Streams
or
pdfView.fromSource(DocumentSource)
or
pdfView.fromAsset(String)
    .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3) // all pages are displayed by default
    .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
    .swipeHorizontal(false)
    .enableDoubletap(true)
    .defaultPage(0)
    // allows to draw something on the current page, usually visible in the middle of the screen
    .onDraw(onDrawListener)
    // allows to draw something on all pages, separately for every page. Called only for visible pages
    .onDrawAll(onDrawListener)
    .onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener) // called after document is loaded and starts to be rendered
    .onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
    .onPageScroll(onPageScrollListener)
    .onError(onErrorListener)
    .onPageError(onPageErrorListener)
    .onRender(onRenderListener) // called after document is rendered for the first time
    // called on single tap, return true if handled, false to toggle scroll handle visibility
    .onTap(onTapListener)
    .onLongPress(onLongPressListener)
    .enableAnnotationRendering(false) // render annotations (such as comments, colors or forms)
    .password(null)
    .scrollHandle(null)
    .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
    // spacing between pages in dp. To define spacing color, set view background
    .spacing(0)
    .autoSpacing(false) // add dynamic spacing to fit each page on its own on the screen
    .linkHandler(DefaultLinkHandler)
    .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH) // mode to fit pages in the view
    .fitEachPage(false) // fit each page to the view, else smaller pages are scaled relative to largest page.
    .pageSnap(false) // snap pages to screen boundaries
    .pageFling(false) // make a fling change only a single page like ViewPager
    .nightMode(false) // toggle night mode
    .load();
```

For More Information [Github: Barteksc Android Pdf Viewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

I Hope, it Helps!