# How do I get the Assets path in an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-file

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm having trouble passing a CSV file to `CSVReader`, which takes a `Reader` in its constructor.  I can use `AssetManager.getAssets()`, but that returns an `InputStream` and I can't get the file path from there, which the Reader constructor needs. My asset path is

```
src/main/assets/dbsource/My.csv
```

I need to get this into

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvPath));
```

I just can't get the path! Thanks.

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820142/how-to-pass-a-file-path-which-is-in-assets-folder-to-filestring-path

Comment: When the app runs, the assets are not extracted from the APK (which is pretty much a ZIP archive) to the filesystem - unless you do that manually yourself. So technically, they are not files and don't have a path. They can be opened for reading though.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell you what you can do without knowing which `CSVReader` you're using, but, assuming that you're using [this one](https://code.google.com/p/secrets-for-android/source/browse/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.java) you can easily use `InputStreamReader` instead of the `FileReader` here, because it accepts any `Reader` subclasses.

Perhaps the even better way would be to wrap up the `InputStreamReader` into the `BufferedReader` like so:

```
final CSVReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    context.getAssets().open("dbsource/My.csv")
));
```