# what is the correct asset folder path in android studio in mac os

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I am trying to load a html into webview.

The following didnt work for me:

```
     webView.loadUrl("file:///assets/index.html");
     webView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/index.html");
```

index.html actual path in my mac is :

```
   app/src/main/assets/www/index.html
```

I even tried:

```
   webView.loadUrl("app/src/main/assets/www/index.html");
   webView.loadUrl("/app/src/main/assets/www/index.html");
   webView.loadUrl("~/app/src/main/assets/www/index.html");
```

I also tried by copying the original file path:

```
webView.loadUrl("/Users/VenkataManiteja/Desktop/MaterialTabs/app/src/main/assets/www/index.html");

webView.loadUrl("file:///Users/VenkataManiteja/Desktop/MaterialTabs/app/src/main/assets/www/index.html");
```

But the webview cant find my file.

What is the proper way to give the file path ?

The following is displayed in logcat:

```
 01-28 16:48:34.452 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
01-28 16:48:34.452 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
01-28 16:48:34.462 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
01-28 16:48:34.472 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
01-28 16:48:34.482 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
01-28 16:48:34.512 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
01-28 16:48:34.522 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
01-28 16:48:34.532 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
01-28 16:48:34.542 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/chromium: [ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(313)] [.Parent-Compositor-0x7fd5bc907b00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
01-28 16:48:34.552 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
01-28 16:48:34.562 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
01-28 16:48:34.572 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
01-28 16:48:34.582 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
01-28 16:48:34.582 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
01-28 16:48:34.582 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
01-28 16:48:34.592 20737-20752/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820142/how-to-pass-a-file-path-which-is-in-assets-folder-to-filestring-path) question

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri, can you check this answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have seen in this screenshot your **index.html in WWW folder** so you can use this code.i have tested this pice of code on mac

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Please let me know if any concern you have.