# Android Studio: FileReader throwing FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

So I know that one of the ways to define a file reader is by saying:

```
    FileReader file = new FileReader(f);
```

where f is a file class.
In my code, I create the file class just before I define the fileReader, and it gives me a FileNotFoundException.

Here is the code that is giving me problems:

```
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stats);
    String baseDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String fileName = "com/example/magulo/testing123/stats.csv";
    String filePath = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;

    File f = new File(filePath);
    FileReader file = new FileReader(f); //this throws FileNotFound
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(file);
```

This is in the protected void onCreate. Stats.csv is a file which is in both a folder named raw in res and is also copied in the same folder as the erroring-code, the java folder.
Why is the fileReader not finding the file? The file is declared without any problems...

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the path of the root of the SD card, not your internal assets.

Comment: how would you get the path of the internal assets? @Andrew Sun

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744169/how-to-determine-the-absolute-path-for-specific-file-from-assets

Answer (score 0):

String fileName = "com/example/magulo/testing123/stats.csv";

String filePath = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;

File f = new File(filePath);

if(!f.exits)
 {`enter code here`
    f.mkidr();

}

Comment: by the enter code here, do you mean declare the file reader inside the if statement? because i do that and i still get a file not found exception...